# css for <a tag> to increase width and height?

Tags: html, css

html

```
<a id='aTag'> a link </a>
```

with css defined as

```
#aTag { 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

The above does not change the width and height of the `<a tag>`

How do you change the width and height of the `a tag` then?

Comment: `a` tags are inline elements by default, which take their width and height from their content. Read more about the `display` property here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display

Comment: How do you vertically align the a link in this? horizontal centering i got using: text-align: center;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try making it a block element:

```
#aTag { 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: inline-block might be good as well.  then it should keep the "inlining" functionality of an anchor.

Comment: Yes, the a tag by default is display: inline. Both answers here are correct.

Comment: How do you vertically align the `a link` in this? horizontal centering i got using: `text-align: center;`

Comment: @SangramSingh you change its margins: `margin-bottom: 5px`, etc.

Comment: okay, but that will be specific to the height i give. No single css rule for it?

Answer (score 2):

`a` is an inline level tag, so width and height won't have the effect as you are expecting of it. If you want your `width` and `height` to take effect you have 3 options.

1. Set `display` to `inline-block;`
2. Set `display` to `block;`
3. Float the `a`  tag, it will automatically turn to block level element,

[**A Reference Guide**](http://www.ahuka.com/?page_id=119)

Comment: How do you vertically align the a link in this? horizontal centering i got using: text-align: center;

Comment: you can use line-height; property for that.

Answer (score 2):

Just by using "**display:**" property in CSS.

If you want to make it a block and want to give Width & height just add "`display: block`"

But if you are trying to add some spacing around then use "`margin: 10px`" or `"padding: 5px;"`

Both examples shown in Fiddle refereed :- http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/axZLW/

Hope this helps!

Comment: How do you vertically align the a link in this? horizontal centering i got using: text-align: center;

Comment: Yes you can, refer the updated fiddle for the same:- http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/axZLW/

Comment: I am referring to the text 'a link' being aligned in the middle. if i change 'top' to 'middle' in the fiddle the whole div shifts.

Comment: Oh, well I guess for this you need to play with **padding** or **line-height**.For reference please check the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/axZLW/